# How to prove $[x^n]C^m(n)=\binom{2n+m-1}{n}-\binom{2n+m-1}{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, analysis, generating-functions, hypergeometric-function

> Recently I founded that
>   $$
> [x^n]C^m(x)=\binom{2n+m-1}{n}-\binom{2n+m-1}{n-1}
> $$
>   where $C^m(x)$ means the $m$-th power of the generating function of [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), that is
>   $$
> C(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4 x}+1}
> $$

If you prove from right to left, then it will be obvious:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left (\binom{2n+m-1}{n}-\binom{2n+m-1}{n-1}\right ) x^n = \, _2F_1\left(\frac{m}{2},\frac{m+1}{2};m;4 x\right)-x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m+3}{2};m+2;4 x\right)=2^m \left(\sqrt{1-4 x}+1\right)^{-m}
$$

> However I want to assume that I don't know the right form, that means I want to **calculate** the left one.

And I found that one possible method is to use Faa di Bruno formula and Bell Polynomials.

**My question:** Is there any other approaches? The approach above is too troublesome, it indeed needs a lot of calculation. **I am wondering if there's more elementary(maybe tricky?) method.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generating function $C(z)$ of the Catalan numbers is

$$C(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$$

and satisfies the functional equation

$$C(z) = 1+ z C(z)^2 \quad\text{or}\quad
z = \frac{C(z)-1}{C(z)^2}.$$

Introducing

$$C_{n,m} = [z^n] C(z)^m$$

we have

$$ [z^{n-1}] (C(z)^m)' = n C_{n,m} =
[z^{n-1}] m C(z)^{m-1} C'(z).$$

This  is by  the  Cauchy  Coefficient formula  ($C(z)$  analytic in  a
neighborhood of zero)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n} m C(z)^{m-1} C'(z) \; dz.$$

Now we put $C(z)= w$ so that $C'(z) \; dz = dw$ and use the functional
equation

$$\frac{m}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{w^{2n}}{(w-1)^n} w^{m-1} \; dw
\\ = \frac{m}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{w^{2n+m-1}}{(w-1)^n} \; dw
\\ = \frac{m}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{1}{(w-1)^n}
\sum_{q=0}^{2n+m-1} {2n+m-1\choose q} (w-1)^q \; dw.$$

Therefore

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
C_{n,m} = \frac{m}{n} \times {2n+m-1\choose n-1}.}$$

We can verify the alternate form

$${2n+m-1\choose n} - {2n+m-1\choose n-1}
\\ = \frac{n+m}{n} {2n+m-1\choose n-1} - {2n+m-1\choose n-1}
\\ = \frac{m}{n} \times {2n+m-1\choose n-1}.$$

Here the branch cut of $C(z)$  is $[1/4, \infty)$ (principal branch of
the logarithm). This is from Flajolet & Sedgwick, Analytic Combinatorics, page 732, Lagrange Inversion.